# Downloaded Azure - Now All Builds Fail In VS2012

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, azure-sdk-.net

I have just started with Azure. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/

Downloaded the Azure SDK, and created the site (an empty mvc4 site). The build fails.

Even worse, ALL my VS2012 websites now fail to build.

Output example (no more info provided)

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Nothing int the event log.

Tried uninstalling and re-installing Azure SDK. Still fails.

How can I get it working again please?

Comment: Can you turn on verbose MSbuild under Tools/Projects & Solutions/Build and Run? Turn both MS Build options to Detailed and see if it tells you more info.

Comment: Without any error info nothing cannot be done... 

Are you missing any tools.Install the required tool using this http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254364&clcid=0x409

Comment: NavaRajan - That is the download I used. @Petar Vučetin - thank for the debugging hint. I will give it a go. The problem could be IISExpress, but I can't get to my computer at the minute to check.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this.

I turned up the verbosity as recommended by Petar. The result...

"project 'testrestart' is not up to date. missing output file"

1. Did a lot of googling - nothing worked.
2. Remembered I had been playing with MS Build a bit earlier that day. Had a look for MS Build. Bizarrely it was a 0KB file.
3. Deleted all the MS Build files and did a repair install on VS2012. Issue resolved.